# Wordpress: create loop in widget api for defined post id

Tags: php, wordpress

Using [WP_Widget class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API), I coded html layout to output single post meta(title, thumb, url, author avatar and name.

Now I need to output meta strings in PHP defined by post ID:

```
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
  // outputs the content of the widget
  echo __( '
      <h4><a href="the_permalink">the_title</a></h4>
      <img src="the_thumbnail">
      <div>the_category</div>
      .....
      ', 'text_domain' );
}
```

and if possible to define the post id as outputs the options form on admin:

```
public function form( $instance ) {
    // outputs the options form on admin
}
```

Comment: You only want details from a specific post ID? Is it the current post? This is a very vague question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here're what I tried on my local site:

#### 1. Create the widget class.

Save this widget somewhere and include it in your `functions.php`:

```
class PostInfoWidget extends WP_Widget
{
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct('post-info-widget',
            __('Display Post Information', 'text-domain'), [
            'classname'   => 'post-info-widget',
            'description' => __('Use this widget to display a specific post information.')
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Display front-end contents.
     */
    function widget($args, $instance)
    {
        $post = get_post($instance['post_id']);
        echo $args['before_widget'];
        if ( !empty($instance['widget_title']) ) {
            echo $args['before_title'] . $instance['widget_title'] . $args['after_title'];
        }
        ?>
        <article class="post post-sidebar" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Article">
            <?= get_the_post_thumbnail($post, 'thumbnail', ['itemprop' => 'thumbnail']) ?>
            <h4 itemprop="name">
                <a itemprop="url" href="<?= esc_url( get_permalink($post) ) ?>">
                    <?= get_the_title($post) ?>
                </a>
            </h4>
            <div class="author-info">
                <span class="author-name">
                    <?php the_author_meta('display_name', $post->post_author) ?>
                </span>
                <span class="author-avatar">
                    <?= get_avatar($post->post_author) ?>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="category-info">
                <?php the_category(', ', '', $instance['post_id']) ?>
            </div>
        </article>
        <?php
        echo $args['after_widget'];
    }

    /**
     * Display back-end form.
     */
    function form($instance)
    {
        $widget_title = !empty($instance['widget_title']) ? $instance['widget_title'] : '';
        $post_id      = !empty($instance['post_id']) ? $instance['post_id'] : 1;
        ?>
        <p>
            <label for="<?= $this->get_field_id('widget_title') ?>">
                <?= __('Title of the widget:', 'text-domain') ?>
            </label>
            <input class="widefat" type="text" name="<?= $this->get_field_name('widget_title') ?>" value="<?= $widget_title ?>">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?= $this->get_field_id('post_id') ?>">
                <?= __('Displaying infomation of post ID:', 'text-domain') ?>
            </label>
            <input type="number" name="<?= $this->get_field_name('post_id') ?>" value="<?= $post_id ?>">
        </p>
        <?php
    }

    /**
     * Save back-end form.
     */
    function update($new_instance, $old_instance)
    {
        $instance = [];
        $instance['widget_title'] = sanitize_text_field($new_instance['widget_title']);
        $instance['post_id'] = absint($new_instance['post_id']);
        return $instance;
    }

}
```

#### 2. Register the widget

Add this to your `functions.php` after you included the above code.

```
add_action('widgets_init', function() {
    register_widget('PostInfoWidget');
});
```

#### 3. Register a sidebar to display the widget.

Add this code to your `functions.php` too:

```
register_sidebar([
    'name' => __('Post infomation sidebar', 'text-domain'),
    'id'   => 'post-info-sidebar',
    'description'   => __('Use this sidebar to display a specific post information.', 'text-domain'),
    'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/WPSideBar">',
    'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
    'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title'   => '</h2>'
]);
```

#### 4. Display the widget.

Add this code to your `sidebar.php` or any templates you want:

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar('post-info-sidebar') ) {
    dynamic_sidebar('post-info-sidebar');
} else {
    // Do something else.
} ?>
```

Now, try it out and customize it to your preference.

Comment: That is brilliant except when I tried to call gravatar url it returns nothing. check the snippet please http://pastie.org/10838706

Comment: @IhabAbdel-Rahim It means that the author email is not an [Gravatar](https://en.gravatar.com) account. Let's go to [Gravatar](https://en.gravatar.com) and register an account with that email then see what happens. Other reason may be *"Show Avatars" is unchecked in Settings > Discussion*. You should take a look at [`get_avatar()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_avatar) function and [Gravatar](https://codex.wordpress.org/Glossary#Gravatar) glossary.

Comment: The method work just fine within my loop and single.php for the same associated account except within this widget gravatar returns default image and author email is shown..check screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/vs7Q2n8.png

Comment: @IhabAbdel-Rahim Have you made any changes to the code? I have just tested it again and it still work fine. The provided code on `pastie` has nothing to do here and somehow, the image is unreachable.

Comment: I did modified some lines to suite my structure and working just fine. I did output post meta (thumbnail_url, post_permalink, post_title, author_display_name, category_name and category_url) except for author_gravatar url didn`t get to make it work when using the shared snippet: http://pastie.org/10839675

Comment: @IhabAbdel-Rahim I can see the picture and the modified code now. The problem is you used `the_author_meta()` which will echo the author email out. Then the output after `md5()` is an incorrect hash. You can try `md5(the_author_meta('user_email', $post->post_author))` and `md5(get_the_author_meta('user_email', $post->post_author))` to see the difference. I recommend to remove lines: 8,9,10 and change `<img src="<?php echo $get_user_gravatar_url ?>">` to `<?= get_avatar($post->post_author, 150) ?>`.

Comment: Great work. Now as I needed to get done :). If you could now help with this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37244516/wordpress-custom-loop-to-exclude-post-id-assigned-within-widget-args/37290997#37290997

Comment: @IhabAbdel-Rahim Ok! I will rep soon.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to use [the loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)?

```
<?php
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
    $r = new WP_Query([
        'posts_per_page'      => 10,
        'no_found_rows'       => true,
        'post_status'         => 'publish',
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => true
    ]);
    if ($r->have_posts()) {
        echo "<ul>";
        while ($r->have_posts()) {
            $r->the_post();
            $permalink = get_the_permalink();
            $title = get_the_title();
            $id = get_the_ID();
            $thumbnail = has_post_thumbnail() ? get_the_post_thumbnail() : "";
            $category = has_category() ? implode(",", get_the_category()) : "";
            echo "<h4><a href='$permalink'>$title</a></h4>";
            echo $thumbnail;
            echo "<div>$category</div>";
        }
    }
}
```