# Wordpress: Custom loop to exclude post id assigned within widget $args

Tags: php, wordpress

Having widget registered in `function.php` to display defined post_id meta:

```
class featured_widget extends WP_Widget
{
  /**
     * Display front-end contents.
     */
    function widget($args, $instance)
    {
        $post = get_post($instance['post_id']);
...
}
```

}

I want to exclude the assigned `post_id` of `$post` from my loop:

```
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
```

Comment: what have you tried? simple php skills this, using a global var to store the variable etc..... you'll never learn by asking people to do it for you

Comment: Haven't you got the answer yet @Ihab Abdel-Rahim ?? If not then someone should try else not.

Answer (score 11):

#### 1. How to get the `post_id` value?

WordPress stores widget data in the options table with `option_name` is `widget_{$id_base}`. Example, when you construct a widget like this:

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct('so37244516-widget',
        __('A label', 'text-domain'), [
        'classname'   => 'so37244516-widget-class',
        'description' => __('Some descriptions', 'text-domain')
    ]);
}
```

The `option_name` should be `widget_so37244516-widget`. Then to retrieve the widget data, we just need to use:

```
$data = get_option('widget_so37244516-widget');
```

But, because a widget can have multiple instances, `$data` is an associative array with unpredictable keys. (Each time we drag a widget into a sidebar and save it, a new instance of the widget is returned).

So if there's only one instance of the widget throughout your site, `$data[2]['post_id']` is the value we need. And if there're multiple instances, we need to loop through `$data`, compare some keys and values to find out the correct one. As always, `var_dump($data)` is very helpful.

#### 2. Exclude the post of `post_id` from the loop.

Suppose `$exclude_id` is the value we got from step 1.

1. You're doing a custom loop, use @hemnath_mouli's method:

```
$query = new WP_Query([
    'post__not_in' => [$exclude_id]
]);

if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
        // Do loop.
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_query(); // Must have.
else :
    // Do something.
endif;
```

Remember to do `wp_reset_query()`.

2. You're using default loop, try @Deepti_chipdey's method in your `functions.php`:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', function($query)
{
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set('post__not_in', [$exclude_id]);
    }
});
```

Make sure to change `is_home()` to your preference page.

Comment: What about making the widget display single sticky and to be excluded from loop?

Comment: @IhabAbdel-Rahim In case you just want to exclude sticky posts, you can use [`ignore_sticky_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters) in your query. It's much more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to exclide a post, then you must use `post__not_in` in [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

`$post = new WP_Query( array( 'post__not_in' => array( $exclude_ids ) ) );`

Hope this would help you.!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use pre get posts hook.

Tyr this code

```
function exclude_single_posts_home($query) {
  if ($query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query()) {
    $query->set('post__not_in', array($post));
   }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_single_posts_home');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Exclude a single post follow the steps which mentioned above

But unless you give post id by separately just made all post which you want to to exclude in a category and exclude it by simple way.

**Exclude Posts From Some Category**

```
    <?php $query = new WP_Query( 'cat=-3,-8' ); ?>// 3 and 8 are category id
```

**Detailed example**

```
    <?php $query = new WP_Query( 'cat=-3,-8' ); ?>
    <?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

    <div class="post">

    <!-- Display the Title as a link to the Post's permalink. -->
     <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

    <!-- Display the date (November 16th, 2009 format) and a link to other posts by this posts author. -->
   <small><?php the_time( 'F jS, Y' ); ?> by <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></small>

    <div class="entry">
     <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>

     <p class="postmetadata"><?php _e( 'Posted in' ); ?> <?php the_category( ', ' ); ?></p>
     </div> <!-- closes the first div box -->

     <?php endwhile; 
          wp_reset_postdata();
          else : ?>
          <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
      <?php endif; ?>
```

Referrence link:[Click me](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Style_Posts_From_Some_Category_Differently)